# upgrading to python3.5.2 still gives me python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, python-3.5, conda

Installed python 3.5.2 tarball from python.org for OSX however when input

`python3`

the result is:

`Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03)`

Tried:

```
conda install python=3.5
```

but got:

```
The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - enum34 -> python 2.6*|2.7*|3.3*
  - python 3.5*
```

Then tried:

```
conda remove -n testA enum34
```

Still getting 3.4 install when input python3

**Edit: Resolved! I updated my /.bash_profile and removed 3.4 paths**

Comment: are you sure that Python 3.5 has really been installed after it warned about conflicts? did you try to re install since you removed enum34?

Comment: No conflicts and yes i did reinstall.